# Add a frame/outline to a plot using Python

Tags: python, plot, frame, outline

I am creating a barplot using

```
ax = lasso_output_df2.plot(kind='bar', title ="Spain Coefficient Variables [alpha_10]", figsize=(15, 10),  legend=False,  fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticklabels(lasso_output_df2.Features)
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

The df is created using pandas.

How do I add a frame or outline to the actual chart itself ?

I have tried the below:

```
edgecolor = 'black'

frameon=False

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)

ax.spine_color('black')
```

**Current plot.**
[image]

**Desired Plot.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the current `matplotlib` style using [`matplotlib.rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams). Just add the following piece of code before doing your plot, then all subsequent plots will apply the update.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(**{u'axes.spines.bottom': False,
      u'axes.spines.left': False,
      u'axes.spines.right': False,
      u'axes.spines.top': False})
```

This will update all the four sides at once. If you want to change only one side you might simple set the values as:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.left'] = False
```